# Android: not getting phone location inside buildings

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

I've a strange problem here. basically I've an activity that shows a list and populate it based on the user's location. There's no problem when the phone it's outside, but when I'm programming and testing the phone doesn't receive any location updates. Of course this is a problem as I can't leave my workstation everytime I want to test something (not mentioning debugging). The phone should be able to get at least the network or the passive location but it's not. here's the code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_macro_zone_list);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location newLocation) {
        location = new LatLng(newLocation.getLatitude(), newLocation.getLongitude());

        loadMacroZoneList();
    }
```

permission it's already granted, so that's not the problem. I tried each provider both alone and together. I never run into such a problem with previous apps. It's quite frustrating, is there anything I can do?

Comment: I am using the new LocationFusedApi for getting user location and I don't have such problem in getting user location even inside. May be you should try that

Comment: @sumit I didn't know that, thank you. unfortunately, I tried and it doesn't work either :(

Comment: that shouldn't be happening I am using that in three of my applications. can you share your updated code??

Comment: yeah that shouldn't happen with the previous code neither >.<. however I spend a little time in debugging and find out that onConnect it's never called. but neither onConnectionSuspended nor onConnectionFailed are called. my network it's fully working of course